# Accepting a dynamic action method parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm building an app where I have a "Checkout" action which should handle checkouts for any of several different models. It will perform slightly different steps depending on which model is passed to it, but not different enough (I don't think) to justify creating separate actions.

Here's a simplified idea of what I'm working with:

```
public class FooEstimate {
    public Guid Id;
    public DateTime BeginDate;
}

public class BarEstimate {
    public Guid Id;
    public DateTime BeginDate;
    public string BarSpecificField;
}

public ActionResult Checkout (???) {
    //process the estimate, etc
}
```

How could I handle this without having to create a separate checkout action for each model type?

Comment: I would create separate actions for each type and a helper class/method to do the majority of work for each action. It's clean, obvious, and the code duplication is probably minimal.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a base class for the estimates:

```
public class Estimate 
{
    // whatever
}

public class FooEstimate : Estimate 
{
    // whatever
}

public ActionResult Checkout (Estimate estimate) 
{

}
```

Or you could just do Checkout (object estimate).

Then you can check the type of the argument in order to perform the next steps:

```
if (obj is FooEstimate)
{

}
else if (obj is BarEstimate) 
{

}
```

Comment: I think your second method is in the right direction, but wouldn't `is` just check if `estimate` inherits `FooEstimate` or `BarEstimate`?